# Change base path for relative and absolute path

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

My goal is deploy my website without change all paths more times. The situation is this:

**EXAMPLE PATH**

```
index.aspx
template.master
--Folder
----img.jpg
----pageInFolder.aspx
```

My template have script and css src as absolute "/js/main.js" and "/css/main.css", in this way the "pageInFolder.aspx" can get the js and css from the correct path, but the images path in the page "pageInFolder.aspx" are relative "img.jpg".

All is obiouvsly correct, but if I want test online the site in a subfolder of the root it can't work properly.

**I want to set a subfolder as the root path, but only in the subfolder context, how can I do ?**

Remember that it is only for testing the site online, I want the fastest solution without change all the path.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually strange to mix relative and absolute path.

Try to put all of them in absolute using a base folder let say "test" in order to have this

```
test
-index.aspx
-template.master
--Folder
----img.jpg
----pageInFolder.aspx
```

Comment: My problem is just that, work as less as possible to get a result that will fit both for the path "root" and for the path "root / test" or "root / whateveryouwant". If I change all paths in absolute then I'll have to change them again when it will be online in the "root", the real situation, out of test. If I have to choose and change everything, then I prefer all relative, for the reasons explained above, with the problem of having to move all paths of template on individual pages, otherwise they will never be properly contextualized.